# Express routing mocha test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have this test code for routing , how to make it function 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
describe("routing",function(){
  it("should call function to return list of obj",function(done){

      var server = require('../server.js')
    request( server ).get('/listt')
    .send({'id':3,'name':'name3'})
    .end(function(err,res){
      console.log("",res.body)
     if(err){
       done(err);
     }else{
      console.log(res.body);
      var expected =[{'id':1,'name':'name1'},{'id':2,'name':'name2'},{'id':3,'name':'name3'}];
      expect(res.body).to.equal (expected )
         done();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your question is really vague, it seems like you need to read up on how to test routes. Here's a good link: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/07/testing-express-routes/

Comment: are you only using mocha or chai aswell?

Comment: no just mocha 
i want to ask .send({id:3,name:"name3"})what this mean

Comment: i mean i want to understand how connect between server and request from client

Comment: how i can explain send({}) in routing

Comment: you are doing a get, you are not suposed to "send" like that , that send from mocha is for body , if you want to send something on a get request you need to search the documentation of mocha for that

Comment: change it to post?like this
    request( server ).post('/listt')
and in route file do it like this
 app.post('/listt',function(req,res){
  res.send(obj.list());
  });

Comment: yep for example, not sure if that syntax is correct tho, i am not used to test with only mocha

Comment: expected is {'id':1,'name':'name1'},{'id':2,'name':'name2'}
how to add last object{'id':3,'name':'name3'}

Comment: you are sending to your server only 3 , and you are expecting the server to return 1 2 3, if the server is not returning 1 2 3 then the handler is not doing his job well, if you are expecting 1 2 3 and it only returns 1 2 then there is a problem, you build tests to see if your app works fine, you dont change the tests to be passable by the version you have

Comment: this function 
list: function(){
    var arr=[{'id':1,'name':'name1'},{'id':2,'name':'name2'}];
    console.log(arr);
 return arr;
}

Comment: and this route for it var obj = require("../controller/mainController.js");

  app.get('/list',function(req,res){
  res.send(obj.list());
  });

Comment: now i have this test describe("routing",function(){
 it("should call function to return list of obj",function(done){
     
     var server = require('../server.js')
  request( server ).get('/listt')
  .send({'id':3,'name':'name3'})
  .end(function(err,res){
   console.log("",res.body)
   if(err){
    done(err);
   }else{
    console.log(res.body);
    var expected =[{'id':1,'name':'name1'},{'id':2,'name':'name2'},{'id':3,'name':'name3'}];
    expect(res.body).to.equal (expected )
       done();
    }
  });
 });
});

Comment: i have to add make routing to it

Answer (score 0):

the basic test you are looking for from your description, is using:

mocha : https://mochajs.org/

chai: http://chaijs.com/

chaiHttp: https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http

then with this 3 you could transform that into something like this:

```
describe("Routing", function() {
  it("should call function to return list of obj", function(done){
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/listt')
      .send('Whatever you want to send')
      .end(function(err, res) {
         //do whatever verifications you want here
         done();
    });
});
```

there is tons of ways to test routings , this is just one of the easyest to get used to(my opinion).

Comment: how to write the routing from this test

Comment: you are way over your head, you are trying to build routing tests , when you dont understand routes first!! just learn routes first and how they work, then worry about the tests.
https://codeforgeek.com/2015/05/expressjs-router-tutorial/